# unity exception when registring types

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, unity-container

I'm working with unity and I created a Test that doesn't work.

When I run the webApp and call `container.LoadConfiguration()` from the `RegisterTypes()` method, I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

> The type name or alias IHolaMundo could not be resolved. Please check
>   your configuration file and verify this type name.

Here is my code:

unity.config flie:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">


  <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration"/>

  <assembly name="unityTest.Data.Hola" />
    <assembly name="unityTest.AppServices.Interfaces" />
    <assembly name="unityTest.AppServices.Servicios" />
    <assembly name="unityTest.UI.ServiceInterfaces" />

    <namespace name="unityTest.Data.Hola" />
    <namespace name="unityTest.AppServices.Interfaces" />
    <namespace name="unityTest.AppServices.Servicios" />
    <namespace name="unityTest.UI.ServiceInterfaces" />

  <container>
    <register type="IHolaMundo" mapTo="HolaMundo"/>
    <register type="IServicioHola" mapTo="ServicioHola"/>
  </container>
</unity>
```

HolaMundo.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using unityTest.AppServices.Interfaces;

namespace unityTest.Data.Hola
{
    public class HolaMundo
        : IHolaMundo
    {
        private string _saludo = "";

        public HolaMundo()
        {
            _saludo = "Hola Mundo";
        }
        public string Saludo()
        {
            return _saludo;

        }
    }
}
```

IHolaMundo.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace unityTest.AppServices.Interfaces
{
    public interface IHolaMundo
    {
        string Saludo();
    }
}
```

ServicioHola.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using unityTest.AppServices.Interfaces;

namespace unityTest.AppServices.Servicios
{
    public class ServicioHola
    {
        IHolaMundo _miSaludador = null;  

        public ServicioHola(IHolaMundo saludador)
        {
            _miSaludador = saludador;
        }

        public string Saludar()
        {
            return _miSaludador.Saludo();
        }
    }
}
```

...and the HomeController Constructor:

```
private IServicioHola _holaService = null;
        public HomeController(IServicioHola servicio)
        {
            _holaService = servicio;
        }
```

any Idea ?

Comment: Have you installed the unity via nuget package?

Comment: Yes Fabio I have installed unity via nuget package.

Comment: Did you set <unity configSource="unity.config"/> in your app.config?

Comment: Yes,  if not,... the Exception will not reference to 'IHolaMundo'.

Comment: Your HomeController and config references IServicioHola but you have not provided any definition for IServicioHola.  Also, the config maps IServicioHola to ServicioHola however in the code the ServicioHola class does not implement the IServicioHola (or any) interface.

Comment: Thanks Randy,... really I provided the definition for IServicioHola but I've not posted....

Comment: I realize that your "real" code is probably "OK" (except that some aspect is not working) but if you want the best (and fastest) help then you should aim to post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).  If there are errors or omissions in the question then it can be hard to focus on the real issue. Just a friendly tip.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the provided XML configuration, the registered assembly names and the namespace names are the same.Please help to double check your Assembly Name of your project. I assume the project assembly name would be `unityTest` or `unityTest.Data`, or `unityTest.AppServices`, which might be missing in your Unity XML configuration.

Please make sure the correct assembly name is already configured in `<assembly name="..."/>`

Steps:
1. With the project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
2. Click the Application tab, and check the Assembly Name field.

Comment: I checked all the assembly and namespaces and they are correct, ... but there is one observation in your response that I don't understand.... You said "...which might be missing in your Unity XML configuration" but I reference to the asemblies and namespaces in the unity.config.... ¿? Is there missing any reference? Thanks in advance

Comment: @JerónimoMolina , 

The assembly name should reflect the real assembly name, not the namespace. 
e.g.
Will your project generates two DLLs with the names "unityTest.AppServices.Interfaces" & "unityTest.AppServices.Servicios"? 
If your DLL name is "unityTest.AppServices", then you need to have the configuration like:

`<assembly name="unityTest.AppServices" />
<namespace name="unityTest.AppServices.Interfaces" />
<namespace name="unityTest.AppServices.Servicios" />`

Comment: I konw what you say, but I'll check one more time  all the assemblies and namespaces,..... Thank you anyway.

Comment: ,... finally the error was that all the references on the UI Project where missing,.... Just added the references and all worked fine.